# How do you style an angular material table?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I need some help with styling an angular material table. How do yous style the headers and the cells?

This is my app.component.html:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.name }}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="rating">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Rating</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.rating }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It seems that you're using Angular (2+) syntax, but you have angularJS imported. I'm not sure if that's related to the issue you're having, but I think you should remove that import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply css on `mat-header-cell` for header style and `mat-cell` for data cell.

```
.mat-header-cell {
  color: red;
}

.mat-cell {
  color: blue;
}
```

See the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-data-source-grwvtc)